# connect to database server without connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, oracle

from the question title is there any way to connect to the database server without using string connection?

I don't wont to but the connection string in the code I want another way.

Is it possible no matter what is the database engine is.

I am building a Windows Form Application using C#.

I mean something like trusted device or windows authentication or by butting a program on server side to do the authentication

Comment: Without connection string, how do you want to set the server name, database name, username, password,...?

Comment: I mean something like trusted device or windows authentication or by butting a program on server side to do the authentication

Comment: Have you ever heard of app.config and the ConnectionStrings section? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: no I have not but according to your link I must provide the user name and password in the configuration file and that not what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using a PHP with Slim 3 Framework to create a Post requests this way I does not have to put the connection string on my app I only needed to send some credential information and on the server said I run a process to check if this credential information is valid or not and to send back  the result or not it is a very difficult way since you need to create your own security methods but it does the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

**You Can't**. You must have a connection string to provide the location of the server and the database name.

If you need to hide the Credentials because you're afraid of Reverse Engineering your code, then you have 2 options:

1 - Use integrated Security ([Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)).

2 - Encrypt your configuration file: Follow this [link](http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx) Or this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx).

Also, you might find this [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164054.aspx) helpful.

Comment: Yes I want to hide the Credentials but Encryption is not what I am looking for.
what about the integrated Security could you please provide me with some more information about it?

Comment: @AnAs51993 link added to answer.

Comment: It look like that I must have an (Intranet) and I want to use the internet^_^. so is there any other ways or should I close the question :(.

Comment: @AnAs51993 for me no. But you can wait. Maybe somebody has a better answer. If you want to raise attention to this question, try to put a *50 points reputation bounty on it*

Comment: @AnAs51993 I added another link for encrypting the config file, i think this is your last hope.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle except fully connection string you can use Trusted connnection(Os authentication) and Kerberos authentication.
All type of authentication you can find there:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT163